# Call On-Screen Keyboard(OSK) using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, on-screen-keyboard

I am using this code below to call `On-Screen Keyboard(OSK)`

```
Process.Start("C:\Windows\System32\OSK.EXE")
```

but as you can see below I got an error. But if I manually open it, it's working fine.

And it is possible to call the OSK but only numeric display `(0 - 9)`
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Neolisk can't load my OSK.. And if it will load. It is possible to load the numeric only?.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to control what users can input via built-in methods like this. You can write your own keyboard. If you described your need in a bit more detail, people could possibly suggest more options.

Comment: @Neolisk I was also thinking to create a 10 buttons for #'s (0-9). I just included the question on my problem when calling the OSK like the picture above

Comment: Is this for Windows 10?

Comment: @MrGadget Windows 7

Comment: There's a mention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800212/calling-the-on-screen-keyboard-using-a-button-in-c-sharp?rq=1) that this doesn't work on Win 10...wonder if it's now locked out for others as well?

Comment: There might be an alternate solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34692931/3992902) that you could convert.

Comment: @MrGadget I hope it will work on `W.7`. I'll try that later I got some works to do :D

Comment: Did you try to go to the debug folder and run the program as administrator?

Answer (score 6):

```
Public Class Form1

    Declare Function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32" (ByRef oldvalue As Long) As Boolean
    Declare Function Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32" (ByRef oldvalue As Long) As Boolean
    Private osk As String = "C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe"
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim old As Long
        If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then
            If Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(old) Then
                Process.Start(osk)
                Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(old)
            End If
        Else
            Process.Start(osk)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you put an explanatory text along with your code, it will be more helpful for other users.

Answer (score 3):

```
Declare Function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32" (ByRef oldvalue As Long) As Boolean
Declare Function Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection Lib "kernel32" (ByRef oldvalue As Long) As Boolean
Private osk As String = "C:\Windows\System32\osk.exe"
Private pOSK As Process = Nothing

Public Sub Keyboard_Show()
    'An instance is running => Dan wordt pOSK het bestaande proces
    For Each pkiller As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If String.Compare(pkiller.ProcessName, "osk", True) = 0 Then pOSK = pkiller
    Next

    'If no instance of OSK is running than create one depending on 32/64 bit
    For Each pkiller As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If Not (String.Compare(pkiller.ProcessName, "osk", True) = 0) And (pOSK Is Nothing) Then

            Dim old As Long
            If Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem Then
                '64 Bit
                If Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(old) Then
                    pOSK = Process.Start(osk)
                    Wow64EnableWow64FsRedirection(old)
                End If
            Else
                '32 Bit
                pOSK = Process.Start(osk)
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'-------------------------------------------------
'--- Hide On Screen Keypad mbv process threads ---
'--- 05-07-2018                                ---
'-------------------------------------------------
Public Sub Keyboard_Hide()
    For Each pkiller As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If String.Compare(pkiller.ProcessName, "osk", True) = 0 And Not (pOSK Is Nothing) Then

            ' Terminate process
            pOSK.Kill()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Wait untill proces is really terminated
    For intStap As Integer = 1 To 10
        For Each pkiller As Process In Process.GetProcesses
            If String.Compare(pkiller.ProcessName, "osk", True) = 0 Then
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
            Else
                pOSK = Nothing
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next intStap
End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private oskProcess As Process

Private Sub openButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
                            System.EventArgs) Handles openButton.Click
 If Me.oskProcess Is Nothing Then
   If Me.oskProcess IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.oskProcess.HasExited Then
            Me.oskProcess.Close()
   End If
        Me.oskProcess = Process.Start("osk")
 End If
End Sub
```